# Why is downvote cast to my question not shown in chemistry stack exchange unlike meta stack exchange? (My reputation is odd?)

Tags: support, reputation

I have only two zero scored questions and no answer. However I got +5 reputation by upvote of [this (my) question.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/95070/62147) How can this happen?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Desktop version screenshot

[image]

[image]

In the meta SE profile rep history, I could see downvote logs though it didn't affect my reputation. However that of SE chemistry doesn't show me any of them (only upvote).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because your question was also downvoted (do you have a -2 in your reputation list?):

[image]

Score = upvotes - downvotes. Hope this helps!

Comment: [Downvotes cannot cause reputation to drop below 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), which is why there is no -2

Comment: Ok, I see @orthocresol

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get the screenshot? I can only see sum of upvote and downvote, not individually even in desktop version.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode you can see the different counts after you surpass a reputation threshold.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン well I saw it actually because I have the TamperMonkey extension :p

Comment: @Martin-マーチン  Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder I see, and whats monkeyExtension?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode TamperMonkey is a service that allows you to customize webpage stuff in your browser. I installed [this code](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep).